# Why doesn't prerender.io work on my apache shared server using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess, prerender

I am a novice Linux user and am trying to ensure SEO rankings for my angular/bootstrap application. I have tried applying prerender.io middleware in .htaccess files in several folders on my shared GoDaddy server, but to no avail. I have reached out to Todd, the owner of the product, but he has not been able to provide a workable solution. He seems a bit overwhelmed.

What am I missing? Where should the .htaccess be located? This  is the [site](http://writers-tryst.ron-tornambe.com/#/) I wish to prerender.

My .htaccess file in the folder preceding public_html:

**UPDATED** (latest complete .htaccess)

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

        # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

        # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
        # BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        # NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
        # the above regex won't work. You can use the following
        # workaround to get the desired effect:
        BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

        # Don't compress images
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80      

# Change YOUR_TOKEN to your prerender token and uncomment that line if you want to cache urls and view crawl stats
# Change http://example.com (at the end of the last RewriteRule) to your website url

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "MY TOKEN"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

<IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
# Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(index.html.var)(.*) http://service.prerender.io/http://writers-tryst.ron-tornambe.com/$3 [P,L] </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT**

I modified the navbar list as follows:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a id="homepage" href="?_escaped_fragment_=/"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="?_escaped_fragment_=/writers/" class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"> Writers</a></li>
```

The angular "when" looks like this:

```
wtApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })
    // route for the writers page
    .when('/writers', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/writers.html',
        controller: 'writersController'
    })
```

The URL looks like this:

> http://writers-tryst-test.ron-tornambe.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/writers#/

The writers page is not displayed. It remains on the home page.

I don't know why the # is added. If I remove it, it just gets reinserted.

I will keep tweaking it - I know I am close.

Comment: why is index.html.var? and why is googebot is not there?

Comment: googlebot should not be in the list of user agents to check since they could penalize you for cloaking. Google follows the escaped fragment crawling protocol so the _escaped_fragment_ section will match googlebot correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to regenerate your Prerender.io token since you exposed it there in your config. Someone else could use your token and stick you with a large bill. Go to the Account section of our website and you'll see the option to regenerate your token there.

Also, you still have $2 even though you have 3 capture groups in that regex. The third capture group is what you want to send to our service.

Did you try the config I last sent you?

```
# Change YOUR_TOKEN to your prerender token and uncomment that line if you want to cache urls and view crawl stats
# Change http://example.com (at the end of the last RewriteRule) to your website url

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "YOUR_TOKEN"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

<IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
# Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(index.html.var)(.*) http://service.prerender.io/http:/%{HTTP_HOST}/$3 [P,L] </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Let me know if that works. Happy to help!

Comment: I changed the token - thanks for pointing that out. I reposted the .htaccess file, after modifying the script as you suggested. I used an online sitemap generator. It didn't return any pages:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->

</urlset>

Comment: You might want to regenerate your token again. Looks like you reposted the .htaccess with your new token. The online sitemap generator won't be able to crawl your pages unless they support the escaped fragment crawling protocol (they probably don't) or unless you add their user agent to your configuration there. It also looks like you are using the # in your URL so you'll need to change it to a #! in order for your pages to be crawled correctly. I'd suggest removing the # altogether and using html5 push state. Please read our documentation about the # https://prerender.io/documentation

Comment: I added the results of the push state changes. I think we're getting closer, but I am still missing something. I can't thank you enough for all your help.

Comment: You should not change any of your URLs to contain the `_escaped_fragment_` query string. You don't want users to follow those URLs. You should only add the <meta name="fragment" content="!"> tag into your <head> and Google will automatically add the `_escaped_fragment_` query string on their own. Are you able to enable html5 push state instead of using the # in your URL?

Comment: My URLs look like this now: http://writers-tryst-test.ron-tornambe.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/#/writers - I am confused about how to implement push state.

Comment: Never mind the URLs in my last comment. They look normal for angular: http://writers-tryst-test.ron-tornambe.com/#/log-in. I am still confused about how to implement push state.

Comment: Try this: http://www.codelord.net/2015/05/12/angularjs-how-to-setup-pushstate-with-html5mode/